# The best way to hide a content

Tags: javascript, css

May someone helps me with this problem, please. I have a toggle animation but when I hide the content alway there's a space between the buttons and the table top. I tried using `display: block` and works, but the animation it gets damaged. I think the problem is the padding and margin of the child tags.

Below I'll put my CSS code and the images with the problem. The first one has a space between the table and the top.

```
.hidden {
    &__details {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: .4s;
        &.visible {
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is this related to javascript?

Comment: Where are the html and javascript codes?

Comment: :) May you please post the entire html and css on a JSFiddle or in the question?  One option would be to set the margin-top: -10px or however many pixels you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Display none property. Because it remove whatever size is consume by particular tag.